# ActiveScaffold: How to remove "Create New" link from top of list page

Tags: hyperlink, customization, config, activescaffold

I want to remove the "Create New" link (the one with the green '+' icon) from the top of a listing in ActiveScaffold. I tried config.create.link=false and config.list.create.link=false but they don't work. This must be terribly simple but I can't find it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Just add

```
config.actions.exclude :create
```

to the configuration section. I had tried this already but was getting errors because of later references to "create" such as

```
config.create.link=false
```

Since create has been excluded as an action, AS does not want to see a config.create later on!

Comment: Unfortunately, config.actions.exclude not only removes the link but also removes the route to the action.